# Installing jQuery-Mobile via bower

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gruntjs, bower

In my project I would like to use jquery-mobile via bower.

Before I can use it I have to run `npm install` and `grunt` subsequently inside of `bower_components/jquery-mobile` before I can use the minified `.js` and `.css` files.

This is quite tedious and if I had to do this for every library that I use, I guess I would fallback to just downlading the files and add them to my project.

So is there a more elegant way to get to those "final" files via bower dependency?

My `bower.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    ...     
    "jquery-mobile": "latest",
}
```

Comment: `bower install jquery-mobile-bower` seems like it has been created a few hours ago :o

Comment: In fact I just stumbled upon that as well. Feel free to add this as an answer. I will accept it when I have successfully tested it...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The fact of having to run npm/grunt process (or not) is up to each author. In the case of jQuery Mobile, probably some external user has registered it without noticing that it needs to run Grunt tasks; Bower unfortunately allows everyone to register packages (is that bad or good? :S).

Also, there *may exist* some Grunt task to install bower dependencies and run their Grunt tasks aswell; if there aren't, it's not too complicated to create one.

Anyway, as it seems that you're in a "hurry" for those final, compiled files, there is [jquery-mobile-bower](https://github.com/jobrapido/jquery-mobile-bower), which has been created and registered into Bower a few hours ago.

```
bower install jquery-mobile-bower
```

Let's just hope that this gets maintained and up-to-date.

Answer (score 7):

Just so you're aware, there is an official jQuery mobile Bower package available. It can be installed via:

```
bower install jquery-mobile
```

Its GitHub endpoint can be found [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile).

Comment: That's what the original question was about.

Comment: @mcepl, my answer provides an alternative repository, which seems to be the official one. Thanks.

Comment: The original question is questioning why the development files are downloaded with this bower repository "jquery-mobile". They dont want to `npm install && grunt` They even specify they used jquery-mobile in their post.

Just trying to explain @mcepl's comment :) I had a ton of trouble with `bower install jquery-mobile`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my solution is optimal, but I removed `jquery-mobile` from `bower.json` and I'm installing and building it with `Grunt`, using `grunt-contrib-clean`, `grunt-git` and `grunt-run` plugins. I came up with this, because I don't want to use `jquery-mobile-bower`, because it's an unofficial repo.

Here's an example `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        clean: {
            jquerymobile: 'bower_components/jquery-mobile'
        },
        gitclone: {
            jquerymobile: {
                options: {
                    repository: 'https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile.git',
                    branch: 'master',
                    directory: 'bower_components/jquery-mobile'
                }
            }
        },
        run: {
            options: {
                cwd: "bower_components/jquery-mobile"
            },
            jquerymobile_npm_install: {
                cmd: "npm",
                args: [
                    'install'
                ]
            },
            jquerymobile_grunt: {
                cmd: "grunt"
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-git');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'clean',
        'gitclone',
        'run'
    ]);
};
```

More details can be found here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7554