# Adding jQuery Mobile to a Yeoman Backbone project

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs, yeoman

I'm new to Yeoman and I'm setting up a new project with the official Backbone generator. I've added jQuery Mobile using the command:

```
bower install -save jquery-mobile
```

When I run the app, require.js reports all of my jquery-mobile scripts as missing. I've read posts on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904433/jquery-mobile-require-js-and-backbone) and [here](http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/Yeoman,+Requirejs,+jQuery+Mobile,+Backbone,+and+a+Lot+of+Config+Problems). I must be missing a step or have my main.js set up wrong.

Here are the relevant portions of my main.js:

```
require.config({
  shim: {
      <...>
      jquerymobileconfig: {
        deps: [
            'jquery'
        ]
      },
      jquerymobile: {
        deps: [
          'jquery',
          'jquerymobileconfig'
        ]
      }
  },
  paths: {
    jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
    jquerymobileconfig: 'jqmconfig',
    jquerymobile: '../bower_components/jquery-mobile/js/jquery.mobile',
    backbone: '../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
    underscore: '../bower_components/underscore/underscore'
  }
});

require([
  'jquery', 'backbone', 'jquerymobile'
], function ($, Backbone) {
  Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727787/installing-jquery-mobile-via-bower). Instead of installing the bower jquery-mobile project, install:

```
bower install -save jquery-mobile-bower
```

which is the ready to go version of jquery-mobile for bower/Yeoman projects. Then reference jquery mobile in main.js as:

```
jquerymobile: '../bower_components/jquery-mobile-bower/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min',
```